# laravel as a docker-compose service - [QueryException] could not find driver

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, mariadb, dockerfile

I create a container for my laravel project using this dockerfile:

```
FROM composer:1.8

RUN apk add --no-cache libpng libpng-dev libjpeg-turbo-dev libwebp-dev zlib-dev libxpm-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo mbstring gd
RUN docker-php-ext-enable gd

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN composer install

CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8181
EXPOSE 8181
```

then I try to use it as a service inside a `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  webservice:
    image: private.repo.com/my_user/webservice
    ports:
      - '80:8181'
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
  mariadb:
    image: mariadb
    volumes:
      - './db:/var/lib/mysql'
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=some_password
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    ports:
      - '443:80'
    environment:
      - PMA_HOST=mariadb
      - PMA_PORT=3306
```

now I am getting error 500 when I want to call my APIs.
(error is [QueryException] could not find driver)

I searched about it and all I found is that it usually about happens because there is something wrong with `.env` file

this is my .env file in laravel project

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mariadb
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=my_db_name
DB_USERNAME=my_db_user
DB_PASSWORD=my_db_pass
```

the `DB_HOST` is the same as my docker-compose.yml file.

I also tried to exporting port `3306` in my `mariadb` service but it didn't work either

where did I go wrong, pls help

-----------update-----------

I also checked the ip of mariadb service and put it on my service container (while they both working, without shutting them down) but the problem remains.

Comment: Have you tried setting the ports for MariaDB in the docker-compose? "ports:
        - "3306:3306"" ? Take a look at https://laradock.io to see some examples. If its missing the driver, is the PHP MariaDB driver installed in the service ?

Comment: @Kiksy yes as I said it in my post before I also tried to export mariadb port but it didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was actually pretty simple.

I had to installed pdo_mysql too

now my docker file is like this:

```
FROM composer:1.8

RUN apk add --no-cache libpng libpng-dev libjpeg-turbo-dev libwebp-dev zlib-dev libxpm-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo mbstring gd pdo_mysql # this line is changed
RUN docker-php-ext-enable gd

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN composer install

CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8181
EXPOSE 8181
```

I found the solution here: https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/62#issuecomment-70306737